# How to populate a const member array based on a constructor argument?

Tags: c++, arrays, initializer

Let's say I have this class:

```
template<int N>
class A {
    public:
    A(const char *s) ...
    private:
    const char buf[N];
};
```

The template is there so that I can configure the array size without dynamic memory allocation (a requirement). The `buf` member is `const` because it is intended to remain constant over the lifetime of the object after the object has been initialized.

To clarify, I also do not have access to the STL.

What are my options to define this constructor so that I can copy the contents of `s` into `buf`? One option is `const_cast` but I'm looking for alternatives that does not require this.

Comment: Can you change `char buf[N]` to `std::array` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 No, unfortunately. I do not have access to STL.

Comment: @Ana can you copy the sources of `libstdc++` or something? Even if you don't have access to `std::array`, you will reimplement it right now. Probably worse than in the original implementation.

Comment: The only way to initialize a constant member is through a constructor initializer list. And the only way to initialize an array is to copy into it. Unfortunately you can't copy into an array in an initializer list, which means you can't do what you want. What is it you want to accomplish? What is the class `A` used for? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? Why does `buf` have to be constant, can't you have the instance of `A` be constant instead?

Comment: Can you use a `MyArray` instead as `std::array` is not available ?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm looking for ways to create a minimal, custom string class for a low-resource micro controller system. `buf` doesn't have to be constant since I can internally ensure it is not modified but I wanted to know if I can flag it as constant as that is what it is intended to be.

Comment: BTW, what's happen if input string is bigger/shorter than `buf` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 that's when your coffee machine takes over your life.

Comment: By far the best solution here is to stop using `const` on member variables.

Comment: `const_cast` is not an option  (writing to const object causes undefined behaviour)

Comment: @M.M Sounds like just removing `const` is the best solution ...

Answer (score 4):

The solution provided by @Richard Hodges requires the class be initialized with char array, as opposed to `char const*`, which *changes* the signature of the constructor. If that doesn't work for your case, then here is one solution which does **not** change the signature:

```
template<int N>
class A 
{
       template<size_t...Is>
       A(const char * s, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
        : _assert(std::strlen(s) <= N, "size of buffer is bigger than N"), 
          buf{ (Is, *s != '\0'? *s++: *s)... }
        {}

    public:
        A(const char *s) : A(s, std::make_index_sequence<N>()) {}

    private:
       throwable  _assert;
       const char  buf[N];
};
```

where `throwable` is defined as:

```
 struct throwable
 {
    throwable(bool b, char const * message){
      if (not b) 
          throw std::invalid_argument(message);
    }
 };
```

The use of `throwable` ensures that `buf` doesn't get initialized with buffer larger than `N` bytes. If however your situation ensures that and thus doesn't need this check, you could remove it. The code should work without it as well, though I'd suggest you to keep it at least in **debug** mode.

Note that the addition of `_assert` as member increases the size of the class at least by one byte. To avoid this, we could use [empty base class optimiation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo) and do this instead:

```
template<int N>
class A : private throwable
{
       template<size_t...Is>
       A(const char * s, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
        : throwable(std::strlen(s) <= N, "size of buffer is bigger than N"), 
          buf{ (Is, *s != '\0'? *s++: *s)... }
        {}
    public:
        A(const char *s) : A(s, std::make_index_sequence<N>()) {}

    private:
       const char  buf[N];
};
```

That saves us 1 byte per instance.

Comment: @M.M: equivalents of `std::make_index_sequence` and `std::index_sequence` are implementable in C++11 as well.

Comment: I like the throwable, if you give it a constexpr constructor (and the same with A), then you can declare the variable constexpr - and this will give you a compile-time exception with stack trace if the string length is wrong.

Comment: @M.M who wouldn't use c++14 unless they worked for a retarded organisation?

Comment: @RichardHodges ridiculous comment

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't this index `s` out-of-bounds if `s` is shorter than `N` ?

Comment: @Nawaz this takes care of the case where `s` is longer and would be truncated, but what about the opposite ? When `s` isn't quite long enough to fill the buffer ?

Comment: @Quentin. Then that part of buffer is unused/unusable.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe still `s[Is]...` initializes it with values from past the end of `s`.

Comment: @Quentin I'm uncertain about the initialization part. Reasonably sure it will default initialize.   Are you stating that as a fact or question?

Comment: @Nawaz I'm worrying about the opposite case : when the passed-in buffer is smaller that `buf`. You still access it all the way to its `N-1`th index, which is out-of-bounds.

Comment: @Quentin: Got it. That is really a good catch. Thanks. See the fix.

Comment: That's a nice trick. And I'm not going insane, that's good too :p

Answer (score 3):

You use an index_sequence and template expansion.

```
#include <utility>
#include <cstdlib>


template<int N>
class A {

  template<size_t...Is>
    A(const char (&s)[N], std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    : buf{ s[Is]... }
  {}


    public:
    A(const char (&s)[N]) 
      : A(s, std::make_index_sequence<N>())
    {
    }

    private:
    const char buf[N];
};


int main()
{
  A<3> a("ab");

};
```

And because const char[] is a literal type, it also allows the class to be constexpr:

```
#include <utility>
#include <cstdlib>


template<int N>
class A {

  template<size_t...Is>
    constexpr A(const char (&s)[N], std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    : buf{ s[Is]... }
  {}


    public:
    constexpr A(const char (&s)[N]) 
      : A(s, std::make_index_sequence<N>())
    {
    }

    private:
    const char buf[N];
};


int main()
{
  constexpr A<3> a("ab");

};
```

> but that changes the signature...

ok then, this:

```
#include <utility>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>


template<int N>
class A {

  template<size_t...Is>
    constexpr A(const char *s, size_t len, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    : buf{ (Is <= len ? s[Is] : char(0))... }
  {}


    public:
    constexpr A(const char *s) 
      : A(s, strlen(s), std::make_index_sequence<N>())
    {
    }

    private:
    const char buf[N];
};


int main()
{
  constexpr A<10> a("ab");

};
```

Comment: Note that you change signature to take exactly `N` char.

Comment: @RichardHodges: I've solved  that :P (see my solution)

Comment: @Nawaz depends what N represents I guess - length or limit. Who knows, it wasn't specified by the OP. I have a class like this in my own library called value::immutable::string_type<N>. I actually deduce N via a free template function. This allows compile-time string manipulation.

Comment: BTW, if you support truncation for `char const*`, you could support it for `char const[]` as well, for that you need to deduce the size.